# Getting buttons element to work with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: button, internet-explorer-11

I have the following test code working for all the browsers except for Internet Explorer 11:

```
<button type="button" id="index_next" class="button_next" onclick="alert(this.id);" >Next</button>
```

I have created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lebonam/98noqebz/)

Please assist. How do I get this working for IE11.

thanks

Comment: I have seen a problem with button rendering (only in IE11).  The issue is that in the rendered code, the type="button" attribute is somehow  moved to the end of the tag.  The issue can be worked around (in developer toolbar) by editing as HTML and moving the attribute back to the start of the tag (ie- <button type="button" class=....> instead of <button class=... type=button>.  I assume this is a paint/render issue, but haven't found any clear description of cause or workarounds.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Dallas. I have since resolved using

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

This has created a level of compatibility with other browsers,but have experienced odd behaviours in other features like websockets when using IE11. Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: Please don't use the answer functionality for comments such as `Thank you`, `Me too`, and `Additional Questions`.