# IE-11 Link in HTML Button tag Fails to work- How to fix?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, button, hyperlink

This code works in Chrome but not in IE-11. How can I fix it without doing a  CSS Button?

```
<?php
echo "<button type='button'><a href='".$this_page."?page_num=".$next.$id2pass.$alpha2pass.$date2pass."'>Next</a></button>";
?>
```

I'm guessing using CSS to create/simulate a button may work but I am wondering if the above code can be fixed to work with the simple HTML Button Tag.

Thanks for any help.

PS - I''m sure the answer to this question exist somewhere on the net but I have so far failed to find it so this last ditch effort :-)

Comment: This has been already answered, please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33067104/getting-buttons-element-to-work-with-internet-explorer-11)

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the rendered HTML and not just the concated string that your sever sends. Also what is meant by "does not work", is it a style issue an href issue?

Comment: ...then don't do that! Just style the link

Comment: Mplungjan and Naren, Virtually all questions have already been answered somewhere on the net. The issue, of course, is can one find the proper answer in a reasonable length of time... and I can tell you for one that I put off posting a question on stackoverflow to absolute last resort because of the "tude" I see here.
Also, regarding all the instructions on how to ask a good question... in the process of education, there are NO bad questions. Were stackoverflow a classroom no student would ever raise their hand to ask a question for fear of being treated poorly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not allowed to place a `<a>` link element inside a `<button>` element. Some browsers will actually do what you want, and some won't. If you must have a button that acts as a link, there are two solutions:

**Style the link**

Use only the `<a>` element and use CSS to style it like a button (which you have indicated you don't want).

**Wrap button in form**

Wrap the `<button>` in a `<form>` and set the link target as the form's `action` attribute:

```
<form action="https://www.google.com">
  <input type="submit" value="Google it!" />
</form>
```